# trim function not working on result of to_char

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c

The query

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '0' FROM  '003') FROM DUAL;
```

gives the result `3` as expected
but the query:

```
select TRIM(BOTH '0' from TO_CHAR(3,'000')) from dual;
```

gives `003`

I need the result to be as the first query ('3') but I also need the 'TO_CHAR' (I'm using it to create a virtual column from a NUMBER column).

I can not figure why and how to fix it.
Also, I can not use regex_replace instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `FM` format model to not include the leading white space.

```sql
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '0' from TO_CHAR(3,'FM000'))
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | TRIM(BOTH'0'FROMTO_CHAR(3,'FM000')) |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | 3                                   |
> ```

If you want a generated column then:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value         NUMBER,
  trimmed_value VARCHAR2(10)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TRIM(BOTH '0' FROM TO_CHAR(value, 'FM000')))
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE | TRIMMED_VALUE
> ----: | :------------
>     0 | null         
>     3 | 3            
>    30 | 3            
>   100 | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=82217e6030bea21baa8c121efcc5507a)*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `TRIM`, you can achieve your result 33 by using the following statement:

```
select substr (00033,instr(000,-1))from dual
```